# Why this ActionScript program isn't working?

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

It shows me an error of :

`1120: Access of undefined property myArray.    DataGrid.mxml   /DataGrid/src   line 10`

Source Code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable]
            public var myArray:Array = new Array();
            myArray[0] = "Tom"; // string

            [Bindable]
            public var arrColl:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(myArray);

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="ad"
                         columns="{myArray}"
                         dataProvider="{arrColl}"/>
</mx:Application>
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn’t write arbitrary code directly in a script block like that unless you know exactly what you’re doing. Rather, you should do something like this:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                initialize="initialize()">
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

      [Bindable]
      public var myArray:Array = new Array();

      [Bindable]
      public var arrColl:ArrayCollection;

      private function initialize() : void
      {
        myArray[0] = "Tom";
        arrColl = new ArrayCollection(myArray)
      }
    ]]>
  </mx:Script>
  <mx:AdvancedDataGrid columns="{myArray}" dataProvider="{arrColl}"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Another problem with this code is that `myArray[0] = "Tom"` will not cause the data grid to be updated. For that, you would have to assign to the variable `myArray` itself (e.g. `myArray = ["Tom"]`).

Comment: Error : `TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "Tom" to mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridColumn.`

Comment: -1.  Why would you bind an array of strings to the columns property of a DataGrid?  That is most likely the reason for the runtime error. And why when someone points out a runtime error in your code would you say "Read the docs".

Comment: Oh, you’re downvoting me because I didn’t fix all of the countless problems in your hopelessly confused example?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Look at the original question and you will understand.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com If you think this is such an amazingly well-formulated question, why don’t you just answer it yourself in all the glorious detail you apparently think it deserves, instead of going around downvoting unrelated posts of mine?

Comment: @Daniel Brockman I didn't notice the same bug was in the code posted by the original question.  However, isn't it more productive for you to point out that error as opposed to telling poster to "read the docs"?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Yes, sorry, I apologize. I will keep this in mind.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Please, go ahead and write a more comprehensive answer if you feel like it. I’ll be the first to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't start assigning values to the array in the class definition.  You need move your `myArray[0] = "Tom";` line inside of a method.  If you want it to be happen at initialization, then specify an event handler in the Application tag `creationComplete="yourEventHandler"`, and put the line in `yourEventHandler()`.  Hope that helps, let me know if you need more code :)

Comment: Error : `TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "Tom" to mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridColumn.`